# Java class member not being initialized in constructor?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a custom view in Android. The class member `r` does not seem to be initialized by the time `onDraw()` is called. However `paint` is still successfully initialized (if I remove that line from the constructor, the app force closes). On the last line, I have the canvas draw `r1`, which succeeds and a blue rectangle is drawn. If I replace `r1` with `r`, it's just white.

This is a simplified version of my problem. I've been getting null pointer exceptions for an array member that is initialized in the constructor. But the issue seems to be the same no matter what. Why isn't it staying instantiated?

```
public class ColorListView extends View {
Paint paint;
Rect r;

public ColorListView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    paint = new Paint();
    r = new Rect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
}


protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas){
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    Rect r1 = new Rect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
    canvas.drawRect(r1, paint); // doesn't work if r is passed to drawRect?
}}
```

Comment: are you 100% certain that THIS is the constructor that runs, and not any other of the constructors? `View` has about 3 different constructors.

Comment: are you resetting r somewhere in the code?

Comment: If `onDraw` is invoked by `super(...)` then indeed `r` will not be initialized yet, so `onDraw` will not be able to use it.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce This is the only constructor I'm using, so...yes?

Comment: @SMA No, you're seeing all the code that I use when I encounter this problem.

Comment: Oh. I guess you could have moved the initialization above the `super(...)` call then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On the last line, I have the canvas draw r1, which succeeds and a blue
>   rectangle is drawn. If I replace r1 with r, it's just white.

```
r = new Rect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
```

you can do it on the constructor because at that point `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` return 0. You have to wait until the view is actually measured. On the [documenation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) you can find more information about the [onMeasure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure(int,%20int)) callback

Comment: Thank you. I moved that line to an override of onMeasure() and it worked.

Comment: Followup question--now I'm initializing the `Rect` in the constructor as is considered best practice (actually an array of Rectangles which is what I wanted). Now I set `r.bottom` and `r.right` in `onDraw()` and it works fine, but I'm wondering if I should do it in `onLayout()` instead? Or does it not matter?

Comment: yes you are right. You can just call the setter,  but you have to wait until the view is measured otherwise those methods return 0. In this case, calling the setter in onDraw, or onMeasure or onLayout, does not make that much difference.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing something like this:
In the place you call the constructor

```
ColorListView myView = new ColorListView(context, attrs);
myView.createRectangle();
myView.invalidate();
```

In the class

```
public class ColorListView extends View {
    Paint paint;
    Rect r;

    public ColorListView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        paint = new Paint();
    }


    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas){
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
    }

    public void CreateRectangle() {
        Rect r = new Rect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
    }
}
```

Or find when the view is actually created. The above is a quick way I just made up a sec ago. I dont remember when the view gets created/measured.

PS - I just saw the answer onMeasure(), my bad for not thinking :P

Comment: After I realized that the `Rect` WAS being initialized, just improperly, I moved it back to the constructor and assigned `r.bottom` and `r.right` in `onDraw`.

Answer (score 0):

Rect r is initialized before the View has been measured, so getWidth and getHeight are 0.

Try initializing it after the onMeasure of your View.

Also, it's a bad practise to do

```
Rect r1 = new Rect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
```

in your

```
onDraw (Canvas canvas)
```

You should avoid object allocation in there.